# Exclusion Scripts for already in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

There are 5 version of  Journey and all older version are still finishing and version 5 is currently running. Now I need to change the exclusion script in all email steps.

There are two ways I am thinking of:

1. The exclusion script has  Data Extension. I need to change the base table in that DE from A to B.  Whether is it possible?
2. Or I can create new DE for table B and change all exclusion scripts.   It would be tedious as each version has around 10 to 15 email step with exclusion script.

Also, Important thing I am trying to understand here is What will happen to subscriber already in the Journey (finishing/running).

Whether Email will be excluded from sending email (if they were part of journey already) from the moment I changed the DE/exclusion script.
I know Exit criteria is only effective for new journey in new version and not for already running journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the email in a running journey and it will apply the new configuration to any subscriber that enters that activity after you update the activity. So if you update the exclusion script in the email within the journey canvas a subscriber that is evaluated tomorrow in that email activity will be evaluated on the current script

Comment: thanks for your response great thanks